# postgres update key inside jsonb field

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

i'm using Postgres database and laravel framework
I have jsonb field containts :

```json
{
    "patientInfo": {
        "id": 1612038632,
        "gender": "female",
        "lastName": "تست",
        "firstName": "تست",
        "phoneNumber": "9399999999"
    },
    "cancelInfo": {
        "channel":"Assistant"
    }
}
```

how can i write query to update only patientInfo and keep other keys with no change?
the table name is appointment_requests and the field name is detail.
I wrote this query but it needs to be fix:

```
AppointmentRequest::where('registerar_id', Auth::guard('PATIENT')->user()->account_id)
                    ->whereRaw(" \"detail->patientInfo\" @> '{\"id\": \"$request->otherPatientId\"}'")
                    ->update(['detail' => ['patientInfo' => json_encode($data)]]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing something like the example in  [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#updating-json-columns)?

Maybe  `->update(['detail->patientInfo' => json_encode($data)])`